# tkinter python3.5 osx to open .askdirectory in top of everything

Tags: macos, tkinter, python-3.5

I'm using python3.5 tkinter osx sierra
have a look at this simple example:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.focus_force()

folder = filedialog.askdirectory()
```

when the osx finder windows is open it is behind:
sublime text /terminal/ idle /  (when I run the script from there)

how can I make the finder windows always to pop up on top of everything?

Cheers
D

Answer (score 0):

This occurs on Linux as well. And this is where the solution was tested. First, the reason it occurs. The root window is the parent of the filedialog. The concept of a window group is tightly adhered to on Linux (and apparently Osx). Ordinarily, the filedialog is placed over the parent window, but when you withdraw the parent window, it has no active geometry to draw from. The solution is to call the filedialog before withdrawing root. So here's how that is done.

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.focus_force()
# Cause the root window to disappear milliseconds after calling the filedialog.
root.after(100, root.withdraw)

folder = filedialog.askdirectory()
```

Comment: thanks , I tried exactly like you mentioned  and the finder window is over eveything but the: sublimetext UI /Idle UI/ Terminal UI, I do have the same issue as before.